# sed remove special characters and spaces in line

Tags: sed, regular-expression

**Input**

```
[*] 111, 22, 33, 44
```

**Output**

```
111,22,33,44
```

Using `sed` command `sed 's/^\[\*\][[:space:]]*//' file` were able to display the output as `111, 22, 33, 44` which means space still there.

**So what is the correct `sed` command?**

Comment: If you just want to remove certain characters I find the GNU version of `tr` easier to use, which supports a `-d` parameter to delete characters instead of translating them and also supports certain character classes. In this case just `tr -d '[*][:space:]'` might work well for you. But if you really meant to only change lines with a `[*]` prefix you would be better of with `sed`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that this should do what you want:

```bsh
sed 's/[][*]\|[[:space:]]//g'
```

Test it out like so:

```bsh
echo '[*] 111, 22, 33, 44' | sed 's/[][*]\|[[:space:]]//g'
```

Output:

```
111,22,33,44
```

A longer explanation follows.

---

The key ingredient that your expression was missing was the use of [the `g` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Global-substitution) to perform global substitution. Without this command only the first match on each line will be replaced.

The most counter-intuitive bit (in my opinion) of my solution is how to include the square brackets inside a character class. For that, we refer to the [sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions):

> ```
> ‘]’
>     ends the bracket expression if it’s not the first list item.
>     So, if you want to make the ‘]’ character a list item, you must put it first.
> ```

For further discussion on that topic, see the following post on SeverFault:

- [Using sed to remove both an opening and closing square bracket around a string](https://serverfault.com/questions/466118/using-sed-to-remove-both-an-opening-and-closing-square-bracket-around-a-string)

Alternatively, you could have taken your expression and piped it into another `sed` command, e.g.:

```bsh
echo '[*] 111, 22, 33, 44' \
| sed 's/^\[\*\]//' \
| sed 's/[[:space:]]//g'
```

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @terdon i were unable to accept the answer within the first 7 minutes :d that's why i were waiting the time to done and was doing some other things :D anyway i will never forget to accept the answer for the man who spend time to help me :D so don't worry.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη oh hey, we *all* forget it from time to time! But thanks for remembering!